# A Way So Familiar

Tags: lateral-thinking

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

Bob was mowing is lawn when he saw a white van driving around his neighborhood. Driving the van was a wiry old man. He made stops in front of people houses and took a good look at them. Then he drove out of the neighborhood. Bob was a little nervous but continued to mow his lawn. The next morning Bob had a ring at his door and by the time he got to it, all he saw was the white van driving away. He was even more unsettled at this, but tried to calm down. A few days later, Bob came to his tipping point when he saw the van driving slowly around the neighborhood again. Bob got up and called the local sheriff.

> Why didn't the sheriff do anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sheriff didn't do anything, because the man in the white van is

> A postal worker

Bob is nervous, because he is avoiding

> The IRS, because he doesn't pay his taxes. And the IRS are trying to audit him.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: I was beaten to it on this one - but was going to add that the driver may be checking for house numbers when stopping outside houses and looking at them.

Comment: This answer seems very specific. Could he not have also been _areibhf gung fbzrbar jnf gelvat gb freir n fhocbran_?

Comment: @IanMacDonald - Agreed, *Gur VEF nhqvg natyr qbrfa'g ernyyl jbex, VZB.  Gur cbfgzna jbhyqa'g or gur bar gb nhqvg uvz - vs nalguvat, whfg qryvirevat n yrggre abgvslvat uvz bs gur nhqvg. ...gur VEF jbhyqa'g **abg** nhqvg fbzrbar whfg orpnhfr gurl nibvqrq gur znvyzna.*

Comment: @BruceWayne, V guvax vs V jrera'g cnlvat gnkrf, V'q nibvq nyy srqreny tbireazrag rzcyblrrf naljnl

Answer (score 5):

The van is

> a service van, like [this one](https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2015/04/comcast_van-100577051-large.jpg)

which makes Bob worried thinking

> his services might not be working

The next day, the doorbell rings and by the time Bob gets to it the door, the van is leaving

> And [this](http://3000doorhangers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2-color-Comcast.jpg) is on the handle, saying they missed him.

This would be more upsetting because

> It confirms that something is wrong with his service

The police obviously don't do anything since

> This matter is between Bob and the service provider

Comment: This was actually my original thought, that it was a Pbzpnfg van. But I had problems trying to figure why Bob would call the Sheriff if that was the case.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Given that [this](http://time.com/3071049/facebook-down-police/) is a thing that happened, it doesn't seem too far-fetched.

Answer (score 4):

Not so lateral but

> The wiry old man is the milkman
>  He took good looks at home to see empty bottles and rang at his door because  he put milk.

Comment: Great alterative, but Joe-You-Know has the correct answer.

Comment: Saw that, no problem :) @QuantumTwinkie

Comment: Excellent puzzle. I enjoyed it.